# How to print out the elements of a 2 dimensional array to a textbox in a table like format?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to print out the elements of a 2 dimensional array in a table like format in a textbox, the dimensions are 4, 5 so there is 4 rows and 5 columns. I know I have to use a nested loop but I am new to c# and I just don't know how to construct the loop.

```
//this is my array 
int[,] productsArray = new int[4, 5];
```

The elements of the array have already been assigned. This is the format I'm looking for.

```
        Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
week 1       1        2          3         4       5
week 2       6        7          8         9      10
week 3      11       12         13        14      15
week 4      16       17         18        19      20
```

To give you some more context, this is the code I have already to assign the elements of the array.

```
        String value;
        int num;
        for (int week = 0; week < productsArray.GetLength(0); week++)
        {
            for (int day = 0; day < productsArray.GetLength(1); day++)
            {
                value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter value for " + day + " of week " + week, "Enter Value");
                try
                {
                    while (!(int.TryParse(value, out num)))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number, try again.");
                        value = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter a number", "Enter Number");

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Value entered is not in a valid format");
                }

                productsArray[week, day] += int.Parse(value);
```

Comment: You want to print the whole table in one textbox?

Comment: Note that you'll have to specify a non-proportional (monospaced/fixed pitch) font for your text box if you are using spaces to line things up.

Comment: yes I want to print the whole table in one text box, It needs to be exactly like the format I have provided.

Comment: I have no idea what a non-proportional(monospaced/fixed pitch) font is, to be honest I have no idea what you are talking about, like I said above I am new to c# so please reply in a more simple manner so that I can understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the fromattting with a help of `PadLeft`:

```
public static String FormatArrayOut(int[,] productsArray) {
  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  // You'd probably load week days' names from resource
  String[] weekdayNames = new String[] {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Satturday", "Sunday"};
  int weeksLength = (productsArray.GetUpperBound(1) + 1).ToString().Length;

  // Head
  Sb.Append(' ', "week ".Length + weeksLength);

  for (int i = 0; i <= productsArray.GetUpperBound(0); ++i) {
    Sb.Append("  ");
    Sb.Append(weekdayNames[i]);
  }

  // Body
  for (int i = 0; i <= productsArray.GetUpperBound(0); ++i) {
    Sb.AppendLine();
    Sb.Append("week ");
    Sb.Append((i + 1).ToString().PadLeft(weeksLength));

    for (int j = 0; j <= productsArray.GetUpperBound(1); ++j) {
      Sb.Append(' ');
      Sb.Append(productsArray[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(weekdayNames[j].Length + 1));
    }
  }

  return Sb.ToString();
}

...

int[,] productsArray = new[,] {
  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
  {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
  {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
  {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
 };

String result = FormatArrayOut(productsArray);
```

The outcome is

```
        Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
week 1       1        2          3         4       5
week 2       6        7          8         9      10
week 3      11       12         13        14      15
week 4      16       17         18        19      20
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works but the formatting is a little bit off, the values aren't in line with the days, how can I correct this?

Comment: @SpiritualEvolution: Could you, please, provide some test data? What are the problems? - I've tried to reproduce 1:1 the sample you've put (including double spaces etc.).

Comment: or is there a way to do this without using the append?

Comment: @SpiritualEvolution: I doubt if there's a simple way without Append() since you can have arbitrary number of weeks; another problem is that columns count are also variable, e.g. you can have Monday-Friday or Monday-Sunday table

Answer (score 0):

you can add data to array as follows,

```
for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < productsArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter value for " + j.ToString() + " of week " + i.ToString() + " ==>  ");
                string value=Console.ReadLine();
                int intVal=0;
                if (int.TryParse(value, out intVal))
                {
                    productsArray[i, j] = intVal;
                }
                else
                {
                    j--;
                }
            }
```

and if you need to print all the values in the array to textbox, called txtbx,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < productsArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                txtbx.Text = txtbx.Text + "\t" + productsArray[i, j].ToString();
            }
            txtbx.Text = txtbx.Text + "\n";
        }

        }
```

Comment: As I said above, I have already added the data to the array I even provided the code I used to do so. I know how to print the values to a text box but I don't know how to print it in the format that I also provided. Did you even read the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, firstly note that if you are using spaces to format text layout, you'll need to use a fixed-pitch font such as Courier.

You can format each row of the text by using something called "composite formatting".

Essentially, you can specify the format for an item like this: `{1,7}`. That means: "Take the parameter at index 1 and format it right-justified into an width of 7 characters".

Here's a sample console app which formats the text as you'd like it:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            int[,] productsArray = new int[4, 5];

            for (int i = 0, k = 1; i < 4; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j, ++k)
                    productsArray[i, j] = k;

            Console.WriteLine(format(productsArray));
        }

        private string format(int[,] productsArray)
        {
            var text = new StringBuilder();

            text.Append("        Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday\n");

            for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.GetLength(0); ++i)
            {
                text.AppendFormat
                (
                    "week {0} {1,7} {2,8} {3,10} {4,9} {5,7}\n",
                    i+1,
                    productsArray[i, 0],
                    productsArray[i, 1],
                    productsArray[i, 2],
                    productsArray[i, 3],
                    productsArray[i, 4]
                );
            }

            return text.ToString();
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

To use this in your program, instead of the `Console.WriteLine(format(productsArray));`, just do this:

```
yourTextBox.Text = format(productsArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
string[] days = new[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

        string week = "week ";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb = sb.Append(' ',week.Length+2);
        for(int i=0;i<days.Length;i++)
        {
            sb = sb.Append(days[i].ToString().PadLeft(10));
        }

        sb = sb.Append("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            sb = sb.Append("week " + (i + 1) + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < productsArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                sb = sb.Append(productsArray[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(10));

            }
            sb = sb.Append("\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this one,

```
string[] days = new[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

        string week = "week ";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb = sb.Append(' ',week.Length+2);
        for(int i=0;i<days.Length;i++)
        {
            sb = sb.Append(days[i].ToString());
            sb = sb.Append(' ',5);
        }

        sb = sb.Append("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < productsArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            sb = sb.Append("week " + (i + 1) + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < productsArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                sb = sb.Append(productsArray[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(days[j].Length));
                sb = sb.Append(' ', 5);
            }
            sb = sb.Append("\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```